# Adding a new JSON property to a class from a Nuget

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, system.text.json

I work with a class that comes from a Nuget package, and therefore I can't add properties to it.

Imagine this class:

```cs
public class Base
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }

   // Many other properties..
}

public class Data
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    // Many other properties..
}
```

The JSON payloads I work with look like this:

```json
{
    Data:
    {
       "Value1": "some value...",
       "Value2": "some other value...",
       // Many other properties...
    }
}
```

In other words, the JSON payloads contain a property that does not exist in the Nuget's class - `Value2`.

I am looking for a way to deserialize the above JSON into a class, in a way that gives me access both to `Base` and its properties, and to `Value2`.

I am also in need of doing this both using `Newtonsoft` and `System.Text.Json` libraries.

I have tried creating a derived class, with a nested `JsonProperty` attribute ("Data/Value2") but that doesn't work with either library:

```cs
public class Derived : Base
{
    [JsonProperty("Data/Value2")]
    [JsonPropertyName("Data/Value2")]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried overriding `Data` with in a derived class - that works in Newtonsoft but I lose the base class's `Data`, and it is not supported at all in System.Text.Json:

```cs
public class Derived : Base
{
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    [JsonPropertyName("Data")]
    public Data Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried playing with some custom converters but haven't been able to find a working solution.

What is the way to support an extra property (one that can't be added to the class because it's external), without losing access to the class's existing properties, for both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json libraries?

Comment: Instead of deserializing directly to the target class, you should use a DTO instead. Create a class that doesn't derive from `Base` but instead holds all the properties you receive in the JSON reponse. Then create a mapper that maps between the DTO and the third-party class or any classes you derived from that.

Comment: System.Text.Json and Json.NET are completely different serializers with completely different APIs.  The format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so I would suggest asking different questions for each one.

Comment: @Gil - A DTO is a [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).  @Julian is suggesting you create your own versions of `Data` and `Base` called e.g. `DataDTO` and `BaseDTO`, deserialize to those, then later map them to the real classes using e.g. [tag:automapper].  How many other properties does `Data` have?  Does the external library regularly add and remove properties when new versions are released?

Comment: @dbc yes, that's what I meant. *(Except that I would probably just manually write a mapper or use Copilot to generate the mapper, because Automapper and the like come with their own learning curve and issues and I try to avoid those, but that's a matter of taste.)*

Answer (score 1):

I would not go with this approach, but will post for educational purposes.
as mentioned in comments it would be simpler to serialize to class and map to another one.
this example is showing Custom Json Converter .
P.S. i wrote in a way, than you can put multiple Values3,4 etc. (still stiff code)

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Derived() { Data = new Data() { Value1 = "xxx" }, Value2 = "aaaaa" };
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = { new CustomObjectConverter<Derived>() }
    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, 
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
                        new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[] { new CustomObjectConverter<Derived>() });
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

#region classes
public class Base
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    // Many other properties..
}

public class Data
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
#endregion classes

public class CustomObjectConverter<TModel> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter<TModel> where TModel : class, new()
{
    public override TModel? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TModel? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) is JsonObjectContract contract))
            throw new NotImplementedException("Contract is not a JsonObjectContract");
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var value = existingValue ?? (TModel?)contract.DefaultCreator?.Invoke() ?? new TModel();
        serializer.Populate(jObj.CreateReader(), value);
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TModel? value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        Type type = value.GetType();
        List<JProperty> jp = new List<JProperty>();
        string[] FIELDS = new string[] {"Value2"}; //can have several properties

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                object propVal = prop.GetValue(value, null);
                if (propVal != null)
                {
                    if (FIELDS.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        jp.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name, propVal));
                    }
                    jo.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(propVal, serializer));
                }
            }
        }

        if (jp?.Count > 0)
        {
            jp.ForEach(fe => {
                jo.RemoveFields(new string[] {fe.Name});
                jo.SelectToken("Data").FirstOrDefault()?.AddAfterSelf(fe);
            });
        }
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static JToken RemoveFields(this JToken token, string[] fields)
    {
        JContainer container = token as JContainer;
        if (container == null) return token;

        List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
        foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
        {
            JProperty p = el as JProperty;
            if (p != null && fields.Contains(p.Name))
            {
                removeList.Add(el);
            }
            el.RemoveFields(fields);
        }

        foreach (JToken el in removeList)
        {
            el.Remove();
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a DTO, as suggested in the comments.
This appears to be required, at least until a new, relevant version of the Nuget is released.

Consider this example, when `Base` derives from `BaseBase`:

```
public class DerivedDTO : BaseBase
{
  public string Value2 { get; set; }

  // .. other properties
}
```

And when I deserialize I use the following:

```
public static class DerivedUtils
{
    public static Derived ToDerived(this DerivedDTO derivedDTO)
    {
        return new Derived
        {
            Value2 = derivedDTO.Value2;
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```